# Ruby on Rails undefined method `delete_at' for "John":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, round-robin

I am trying to replace an array of names for a column of names out of a database.
I am new to Ruby on rails so it could be something simple.

This works fine:

```
<% students = %w(John Paul Ringo George) %>
<% teams = RoundRobinTournament.schedule(students) %>
<td><%= teams %></td>
```

This i get an error:

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
<% students = player.first_name %>
<% teams = RoundRobinTournament.schedule(students) %>
<td><%= teams %></td>
```

Error:

```
undefined method `delete_at' for "John":String
Did you mean?  delete
               delete!
```

In the RoundRobinModule the "delete_at" what causes the error:

```
require 'round_robin_tournament/version'

module RoundRobinTournament
   def self.schedule(array)
     array.push(nil) if array.size.odd?
     n = array.size
     1.step(n / 2, 1).each do |i|
       array.insert(n - i, array.delete_at(i))
     end
     pivot = array.pop
     games = (n - 1).times.map do
       day = [[array.first, pivot]] + (1...(n / 2)).map { |j| [array[j], array[n - 1 - j]] }
       array.rotate!
       day
     end
     array.push pivot unless pivot.nil?
     games
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`students` is supposed to be an array, yet `students = player.first_name` makes it a string.

I don't know if this is want you want, but the following should work:

```rb
<% students = @players.pluck(:first_name) %> # or @players.map(&:first_name)
<% teams = RoundRobinTournament.schedule(students) %>
<td><%= teams %></td>
```

Use `.pluck` if `@players` holds an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or `.map` if it's an array of `Player` objects.

But, the error tells you exactly what & where the problem is. You just need to pay attention. The code would have crashed earlier but both `String` and `Array` respond to `.size`.

Comment: I feel stupid razvans. It works!!!! Both, thank you!!!

Comment: No worries. You are welcome.